# "This" in a draggable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

How can I get the attr of a draggable? (only the one I drag)
ui and ui.draggable do not work. Please explain when to use each one
I have been searching and I do not see the solution:
http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#event-drag

```js
$( ".blue" ).draggable(
  { drag: function( event, ui ) { // mentre arrossego
  //var drag = ui.position.left; //ok
  //var id = this.attr('data-id'); //no
  //var id = ui.attr('data-id'); //no
  //var id = ui.draggable.attr("data-id")//no
  $("#check").html(id);
  }  
});
```

```css
.blue { 
 float:left;
 display:inline-block;
 width:30px; height:30px;
 margin:10px;
 background:blue;
 cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="blue" data-id="220"></div>
<div class="blue" data-id="221"></div>
```

Comment: $(this) should be the .blue element that is being dragged inside of your method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$(this) refers to the element being dragged:

```
$(this).data('id')
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/2bv5s0f0/)**

Comment: Yes, it works. I am still confused. When should I use ui. ui.draggable or $(this) ? Why ui.position, and $(this).data('id') ?

Comment: In this instance, `$(this)` equals `$(ui.helper[0])`